# custom keyboard implementation for images in android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I want to implement a keyboard just like this one:

[image: Gif Keyboard]

This application is in Google Play: [Gif Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bo.pic.android.keyboard)

This keyboard can be select from the keyboard list and user can use it from any application.

So far i have learnt keyboard preview can be altered in java code by overriding onDraw(), if so how this can be done

Comment: Hey , did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out the problem. The problem is i was trying to manipulate keyboard view but i don't have to. All i need to do is create any view for input service.

Comment: you mean our view can be embed with existing device app like messanger app, email etc? or no. I am trying similar solution but no success.

Comment: yes u can, but u have to select ur custom keyboard from the settings > language & input and select your keyboard as the current keyboard :) @Parwej

Comment: Hey can you help me with a tutorial?

Comment: then i have to make one as there was no available resources when i have implemented my own image sharing keyborad!! but its easy as u have to use a gridview and u should know how item selections in gridview works.

Comment: Hey I am trying to make custom emoji keyboard where i can share my emoji images in messaging email etc. Can you please help me in that? i am getting [OBJ] as emoji when I use my keyboard for messaging or email or anywhere. Please help!

Comment: Hey @Fay007, how did you choose to implement sending the gifs from the keyboard?

Comment: @Fay007 Can you please provide a tutorial for implementing gif keyboard man. It would be really useful.